# How can I target multiple versions of .Net in a single application transparently to users?

Tags: .net, wpf, windows, winforms

I want to take advantage of the new features of WPF without breaking users that don't have .Net 3.5. I suppose if it doesn't already exist in .Net I would just need to build a loader exe that loads and executes either the .Net 2.0 or .Net 3.5 version depending on the current environment. Any better ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you *really* want to do this - doing so would imply that you'd be writing (essentially) the same application twice. This will set you up for huge maintainability problems, like a bug in your WinForms app that doesn't manifest in WPF (or vice versa). Also, you'd need to implement any new features you add in both WinForms *and* WPF (not to mention porting all of your existing features to WPF). I would **strongly** recommend either sticking with WinForms, or take the plunge, switch to WPF, and require your users to install .NET 3.5.

**Note:** I've found that, once I made the jump to WPF, WinForms development was an absolute CHORE.

Comment: I was planning to basically freeze the WinForms version. I want to make the transition graceful so as not to force an upgrade to .Net 3.5 with my next ClickOnce update.